# ssh on raspberry is not responsive

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am encountering an issue on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ where the ssh shell is insufferably sluggish, to the point that the connection can time out sometimes. I have installed the latest version of raspberry pi OS (Buster), placed an empty file named "ssh" on the boot partition, and have run `sudo raspi-config`on it already. I have, however, noticed that running `ping [HOSTNAME].local` in the background seems to fix the issue. Another notable thing is, running a peer-to-peer connection on a Raspberry Pi Zero as a RNDIS Ethernet gadget with the same SD card shows no issues, although the problem reoccurs running it via router using my Raspberry Pi Zero W. Including that, and with the fact that I have reinstalled the image multiple times so far, I would conclude that there is a fault either in the router or official image configuration files (keeping in mind that on the same network there are multiple other ssh devices that work perfectly fine, making former unlikely).

Comment: How are you connected? Wired or wireless?

Comment: in the case of Pi 3B+, it is connected over wire, but the laptop im ssh-ing into it is over wi-fi. Zero W was connected over wi-fi, over a router, and Zero was connected over a USB cable.

Comment: There are many things that cannot be compared at all, so it will be hard to find any suggestions from outside.